# Is it true that $\pi:X\longrightarrow X/A$ is open and $\textrm{ker}(\pi)$ is closed when $X$ is Hausdorff and $A$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $A\subseteq X$ is compact then $\pi:X\longrightarrow X/A$ is open and $\textrm{ker}(\pi)=\{(x, y)\in X\times X: x\sim y\}$ is closed in $X\times X$?

I guess I proved the second part:

**Proof:** I afirm $$\textrm{ker}(\pi)=\Delta(X)\cup (A\times A),$$ where $$\Delta(X)=\{(x, x): x\in X\}.$$ In fact, $$(x, y)\in \textrm{ker}(\pi)\Rightarrow x\sim y\Rightarrow x=y\ \textrm{or}\ x, y\in A\Rightarrow (x, y)\in \Delta(X)\cup (A\times A).$$ On the other hand, $$(x, y)\in \Delta(X)\cup (A\times A)\Rightarrow x=y\ \textrm{or}\ x, y\in A\Rightarrow x\sim y\Rightarrow (x, y)\in \textrm{ker}(\pi).$$ Is it right?

As to the first part I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the answer for $\ker(\pi)$. Of course you also need to remark that $X \times X$ is Hausdorff too and $A \times A$ is compact in this space, so is closed (using Hausdorff). And $\Delta(X) \subset X \times X$ is closed iff $X$ is Hausdorff as well.

Suppose $O \subset X$ is open. Then $\pi[O]$ is open in $X/A$ iff $\pi^{-1}[\pi[O]]$ is open in $X$, by the definition of the quotient topology. If $O$ does not intersect $A$, one can check that $\pi^{-1}[\pi[O]] = O$, which is indeed open. If $O$ does intersect $A$, then $\pi^{-1}[\pi[O]] = O \cup A$, which need not be open (find an example!).

The same type of reasoning will show that $\pi$ is a closed map.

Added, based on the comment: if we want to show that $X/A$ is Hausdorff when $X$ is Hausdorff and $A \subset X$ is compact, there is a more direct approach.

Lemma: if $X$ is Hausdorff and $A \subset X$ is compact and $x \notin A$, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $x \in U$ and $A \subset V$.

Proof: for each $a \in A$ we pick disjoint open sets $U_a$ and $V_a$ of $X$ such that $x \in U_a$ and $a \in V_a$. We can do this using Hausdorffness (and the Axiom of Choice, if we are nitpicking..). The $V_a, a \in A$ cover $A$, so there are $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in A$ such that $A \subset V_{a_1} \cup \ldots \cup V_{a_n}$. We can define $U = \cap_{i=1}^n U_{a_i}$ and $V = \cup_{i=1}^n V_{a_i}$, and note that $U$ and $V$ are as required.

Now if $[x] \neq [y]$ are two points (classes) in $X/A$, there are basically two cases:

1. $x,y$ are both not in $A$, so they are non-collapsed singleton classes. Then we can pick open sets $U$, $V$ that are disjoint and contain $x$ and $y$ respectively, and are also both disjoint from $A$ (as $A$ is closed in $X$). Then $\pi[U]$ and $\pi[V]$ are open in $X/A$ (as $\pi^{-1}[\pi[U]] = U$ and the same for $V$) and are the required disjoint ($\pi$ is 1-1 on $X\setminus A$) open neighbourhoods of $[x]$ and $[y]$.
2. $x \notin A$, $y \in A$ (wlog). Then the lemma gives us $U$ and $V$ disjoint open with $x \in U$ and $A \subset V$. Then again, $\pi^{-1}[\pi[U]] = U$ as $U$ misses $A$, so $\pi[U]$ is open, and $\pi^{-1}[\pi[V]] = V$ as $V$ is already a saturated set (every point equivalent to a point of $V$ is already in $V$), so $V$ is also open. And $\pi[U]$ and $\pi[V]$ are disjoint (as is easily checked), so are the required open neighbourhoods of $[x]$ and $[y]$ again.

So $X/A$ is Hausdorff. The lemma formalises an intuition that "compact sets behave like points", at least with regards to separation properties. And this allows is to get Hausdorffness when we collapse a compact subset.

If $X$ is regular $T_1$, and $A$ is closed, a similar proof will get us that $X/A$ is Hausdorff again.

Comment: Well this question came us when I was trying to show that if $X$ is Hausdorff and $A$ is compact then $X/A$ is Hausdorff. In this case it would suffice to show $\pi$ is open and $\textrm{ker}(\pi)$ is closed. Now that you told me $\pi$ is not open I don't know how to proceed, any idea?